# find child element of this.selector using its class with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a child element with the class `"pagination"` of `this.selector`, I want to do it with javascript and not jquery how can I do that?

Like in this example:

https://codepen.io/pawelgrzybek/pen/aBQxOw

However I want to add a `<div class="pagination"></div>` to append the the page numbers.

Comment: what is `this.selector`?

Comment: you mind adding some html and or javascript

Comment: https://codepen.io/pawelgrzybek/pen/aBQxOw like this example

Comment: use `element.querySelector('.pagination')` where `element` is the `HTMLElement` object you want to search, such as the `document` or a `div`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

You can use `Element.querySelector(selector)` to select the element you're looking for like so:

```
this.selector.querySelector(".pagination");
```

The above works the same way that you'd expect from jQuery: it finds a child of `this.selector` that contains a `pagination` class.

If you need to grab all children of `this.selector` that have class `pagination`, use `Element.querySelectorAll(selector)`:

```
this.selector.querySelectorAll(".pagination");
```

Comment: Or more simply "this.selector.querySelector('.pagination');" or "this.selector.querySelectorAll('.pagination');"

Comment: the posted code shows that `this.selector` is an element, so you should do: `this.selector.querySelector(".pagination");`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out -- I figured `this.selector` was a CSS selector, but now I see it's an element. I made the corresponding changes to the code.